# Output dimensions of convolutions indicate what?

Tags: tensorflow

```
input = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,5,5,5]))
filter = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,3,5,1]))
op5 = tf.nn.conv2d(input, filter, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME')
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run(init)
print(sess.run(op5))
print(sess.run(tf.shape(op5)))'
```

When I print result output shape is [1,5,5,1]. In this case 5,5 indicates that there are 25 distinct locations for for one filter. What is 1,1 indicating?

Answer (score 1):

The first dimension of the output shape is the batch size, i.e. you have 1 sample in your batch. The last dimension is the number of channels (assuming your data is in the format `NHWC` which is the default). As your filter has size `[3, 3, 5, 1]`, i.e. 5 input- and 1 output channel, the number of channels in the result `op5` is 1.

All this information is available in the documentation for [`tf.nn.conv2d`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d) as well.